# Show values from only rows that have a checkbox ticked

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I have a [data table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w7NvZtziHFk1REZ-Vh2fR-ZhQDuB3WUZtkMA0qCLS7E/edit#gid=0) with groups as column headers and names and emails as rows. I want to export data to another spreadsheet in the same document, which would only display members who belong to a certain group, which would be displayed in separate spreadsheets.

I did dynamically linked them using Importrange, filtered data out and hid irrelevant groups.

The problem is if the master data table has any changes (say, one person was added to group 1), I want them to appear in filtered results for each group without having to refresh the filtering. Is this possible?

I tried to search everywhere, but nothing was quite what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Google Sheets UI filters, use a formula to filter the results.

To do this you could use functions like FILTER and QUERY

Comment: Thank you Ruben, could you please give an example? I'm guessing I need to nest QUERY into the FILTER function but note quite sure how. I've tried this, but it didn't work =filter(Sheet1!D:D,query(Sheet1!D:D,"select TRUE",-1)).

Comment: I've figured it out. This was a great source from Google to help with Query. [link] (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) Thank you, Ruben, once again.

Answer (score 0):

use **`QUERY`** function like this:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:G, "select A,B,C,D where D = TRUE", 1)
```

[image: 0]